# How to get code block with syntax highlighting into LibreOffice Writer

Tags: html, libreoffice-writer, xubuntu

I am using Linux. I want to write small pieces of code and paste them into LibreOffice Writer. I do not care too much about which code editor to use, although preferably it would be ViM or Sublime Text 3.

I have tried several avenues, but all of them are unsuccessful:

- Write the code in ViM and save them as HTML with `TOhtml`. Then, open the HTML file with Firefox, copy the code and paste it in LibreOffice with Paste Special/HTML. The colors are gone, though.
- Write the code in Sublime Text 3 and export it using the [SublimeHighlight](https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight) module. I can copy the text as RTF/HTML, but when pasting it in LibreOffice it pastes the literal HTML code. Paste Special didn't solve it either.

How can one paste HTML/RTF code into LibreOffice Writer?

Running Xubuntu 16.04 and `LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2)`

Comment: Is it acceptable to post the code block as an image?

Comment: @spikey_richie I mean, sure, take this for example: https://forum.sublimetext.com/uploads/default/original/3X/9/9/99c050dd14939dec38c5c843a0cb75cb9b0f572f.png

Answer (score 10):

#### Libreoffice extensions

There are several extensions that allow to highlight a code snippet.
You can search for them in [extensions.libreoffice.org](http://extensions.libreoffice.org).

Among the others

- [code highlighter](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/code-highlighter)
- [code colorizer formatter](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/code-colorizer-formatter)

The steps to follow are usually as easy as

> 1. Insert a new Text Box (Insert -> Text Box)
> 2. Copy and paste/write your code snippet into the text box (You can choose any fonts based on your preference)
> 3. Select the text box
> 4. Go to Tools -> Highlight Code -> Language of the code

<sup>(From Code Highlighter)</sup>

You may need to install

> sudo apt install libreoffice-script-provider-python python3-pip
>   sudo pip3 install pygments

Comment: Note that if instead you decide to use LaTex for a better result, there are macro that will work fine for you in that case too.

Comment: @Hastur: https://github.com/slgobinath/libreoffice-code-highlighter/issues/43

Comment: @einpoklum Good an open bug. Let's hope someone will take it in charge and solve it... I did not write this app I just used (to be honest few, because I prefer to use LaTex ;-) ). BTW It seems there is a fix: _And renaming before installing, the downloaded extension's file name to codehighlighter.oxt, is the solution._. Give it a look if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

it exist now Code Highlighter2 , the successor of 1 (no more maintained):

https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/5814

https://github.com/jmzambon/libreoffice-code-highlighter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The code colorizer formatter link is broken.
The code-highlighter extension works but has two requirements:
Examples are for fedora type distributions, should be similar for debian, slackware, archlinux, etc.

1. Install python3 pygments packages:

   sudo dnf install python3-pygment*
2. renaming the otx prior to adding the extension to libreoffice:

   mv ea4db15f_codehighlighter.oxt codehighlighter.oxt

Writing html for code seems to be overkill.

Comment: Update, the CodeHighlighter2.otx extension installs in libreoffice using Slackware. Works very nicely.