# Can I syntax-highlight text for pasting into a word processor?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, copy-paste, syntax-highlighting, libreoffice-impress, persistence

I have a piece of code (e.g. a C or Java function) which I'm going to put in a presentation. I would like to have this code syntax-highlighted; but LibreOffice Impress (and MS Powerpoint) don't have this feature. And while other editors/IDEs do have it - it's only for internal display, not for copying elsewhere.

So, how can I achieve "persistent" syntax highlighting, producing something in a file or in the clipboard which I can copy/open in my office suite with the highlighting still visible?

Note: I'm on Linux.

Bonus points if:

- The highlighting uses styles (e.g. you can change the color of all keywords by changing a document character style)
- The solution supports adding line numbers as well.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/how-do-you-display-code-snippets-in-ms-word-preserving-format-and-syntax-highlig

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1525126/84724

Comment: This also might help: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18976/syntax-color-config-export/5  or this: https://thisdavej.com/how-to-copy-visual-studio-code-with-syntax-highlighting-to-other-applications/  (Note that both Word and PowerPoint allow you to turn spell checking ... the red squiggles ... off)